# Mount/Unmount SD Card with C# code

Tags: c#, mount, unmount

I want to mount and unmount my SD Card/USB drive with C# code. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: i am searching over internet but not finding helpful thing

Comment: I am looking for code snippet.
Suppose I plugin USB in laptop, that will be automounted. Now I want to unmount that USB from C# code and again mount with C# code.